# Is there a way to get overdue jobs in Quartz.net?

Tags: quartz.net

Is there a way to get jobs that are supposed to be running/completed by now (based on schedule), but queued for some reason (such as threads are used up)?

Answer (score 0):

Not out of the box. You'll have to roll your own. What you need to do is add a listener to the jobs you want to get notifications for. You'll have to implement ITriggerListener and then implement the TriggerMisfired method. Take a look at this tutorial:
[Lesson 7: TriggerListeners and JobListeners](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/tutorial/lesson_7.html)

Answer (score 0):

I'd extend/subclass the job class to include info for when to run, etc, so that you have that data connected to the job itself and not just the schedule/triggers. That way you can just do something like.

```
foreach(var job in SomeListOfJobs)
{
    if(job.scheduledStart <= DateTime.Now && !job.isComplete)
    {
        //do some stufff
    }
}
```